# Provider based Endpoint for weblogic

Tags: using, provider, endpoint, wsimport

Below binding gives error while running the build:

[wsdlc] [ERROR] invalid extension element: "jaxws:provider" (in namespace "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws")

If I place  outside the bindings, there is no change in the skeleton. My goal is to generate Provider based end point based on wsdl.

```
<jaxws:bindings
    wsdlLocation="mywsdl.wsdl"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime'
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='MyPortType']">
            <jaxws:provider>true</jaxws:provider>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me how to generate Provider based endpoint using wsimport?

Answer (score 0):

The correct location for the `<jaxws:provider>` element is in a `<jaxws:binding>` element on the `wsdl` namespace element `<port>`.

For example:

```
<portType name="MyWebServicePortType">
  <jaxws:bindings>
    <jaxws:class name="MyWebService"/>
  </jaxws:bindings>
  <operation name="doSomething">
     <!-- operation (and fault) definition -->
  </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="MyWebServiceBinding" type="tns:MyWebServicePortType">
<!-- .. binding definition .. -->
</binding> 

<service name="MyWebService">
  <jaxws:bindings> 
    <jaxws:class name="MyWebServiceClient"/>
  </jaxws:bindings>
  <port name="MyWebServicePort" binding="tns:MyWebServiceBinding">
    <jaxws:bindings> 
      <!-- PROVIDER ELEMENT LOCATION BELOW --> 
      <jaxws:provider>true</jaxws:provider>
    </jaxws:bindings>
    <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

Adding the `<jaxws:provider>` element as shown above results in the `<portType>` class *not* being generated. In the case above, the `MyWebService` would not be generated.

See here for more information:

- https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/customizations/http.java.sun.com.xml.n/element/provider.html
- https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/customizations/http.java.sun.com.xml.n/element/bindings.html
- https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.3/docs/customizations.html#2.5_Provider_interface